# Pass in a function (by reference) a variable in the scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

There is a way (in angularJS) to pass by reference a variable in the scope in a function (to modify it)?
I've tried but the variable change doesn't happen.
Here my code

```
$scope.modifyVar = function (myVariable){
 myVariable = 92;
}

$scope.modifyVar($scope.txtNumberOfChuck);
```

Comment: There is no pass by reference in javascript, there's pass by something closer to a copy of a reference, but for primitive values like numbers there's only pass by value.

Comment: Expanding on what @adeneo said: JS **only** has pass-by-value, there is no pass-by-reference at all. When you pass something into a function (or assign it from one variable/property to another), the value is copied and the source of that value cannot be modified by the receiver. People get confused in relation to objects, because the *value* variables/properties hold that refers to objects (including functions) is called an "object reference." But object references are still values (think of them as indexes into the biggest array ever), and the reference (not object) is copied when passed.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot pass a variable by reference in Javascript. However you can pass the complete object and get your values changed.

In your case you can pass the $scope object and then modify the property value. Something like this:

```
$scope.modifyVar = function (myObj){
    myObj.txtNumberOfChuck = 92;
}

$scope.modifyVar($scope);
```